# column-marker skips blank lines; how to fix?

Tags: highlighting

I installed column-marker.el. I like the highlighting style better than fci-mode. Unfortunately, column-marker does not highlight bits of the window where the actual line is not 80 chars or more (or whatever its set to). Can this be fixed, so that there's a continuous highlighted strip at column 80? I saw that this issue used to exist in fci-mode, but was fixed. I didn't investigate carefully.

I suppose it's possible to configure fci-mode to display like column-marker, but I haven't investigated this carefully either.

Comment: *Perhaps*, but a screen-shot sure would help.  I would probably use the libraries by Drew instead though (`col-highlight.el` / `crosshairs.el`) and `vline.el` by Taiki Sugawara.  I haven't studied `column-marker.el`, but if it doesn't use `'after-string` overlays, then a marker will not appear if there is no text underneath -- i.e., there needs to be a floating overlay out there in no-man/woman's land to the right of the text.

Comment: If the `:background` color of the vertical ruler is of particular interest to the original poster, then `fci-mode` can be modified -- take a look at `fci-make-rule-string` (which uses only `:foreground`).

Comment: column-marked doesn't seem to use overlays at all, but font-lock, so I guess I'm stuck with trying your other suggestion (eventually).

Answer (score 1):

Library [`vline.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VlineMode) ([`vline.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vline.el)) does what you're requesting.

- If you want the current column to be highlighted as you move around, then turn on `vline-mode`.  (`C-u` turns it off.) Use `vline-global-mode` to do this everywhere.
- If you instead want a particular column to be highlighted and stay highlighted then use function (not command) `vline-show`.  (Function `vline-clear` clears it.)
- See option `vline-style` for different ways to highlight.